Local cohomology of module versus sheaf cohomology
Define the ring $R:=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and define the module $M:=\text{Ker} \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} \subset R^{\oplus 2}$.
Then $M$ has a local cohomology $H^0(M)$, according to the Macaulay2 documentation.
On the other hand, $M$ defines a sheaf of functions over $X=\text{Proj}(R)$, say $F$.
This has a sheaf cohomology $H^0(F)$.
The following Macaulay2 code checks that $H^0(F) \cong H^0(M) \cong 0$:
R = QQ[x,y]
X = Proj(R)
M = ker matrix {{x,y}}
F = sheaf M
HH^0(M)
HH^0(F)


Question 1: what is the definition of local cohomology?


Question 2: is it true for general rings $R$ and modules $M$ that $H^0(F) \cong H^0(M)$?


Does Google not work for question 1?

@Daniel: I found the Google search results difficult to interpret, because there seems to be more than one thing called local cohomology. I believe what Macaulay2 computes is Definition 1.2.1 from "Brodmann, Sharp: Local Cohomology" for the choice $\mathfrak{a}=(x,y)$, but I'm not sure.

Are you just looking for a definition, or precisely the definition implemented in Macaulay2? There’s only one notion of local cohomology in commutative algebra/algebraic geometry.

I'm looking for the definition implemented in Macaulay2. I see at least two definitions of local cohomology: the one from my last comment and definition 9.1 "Iverson: Cohomology of sheaves". (These are the two definitions mentioned as "geometric form" and "algebraic form" under Definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_cohomology ). I don't see how these two definitions are equivalent.

You may find this helpful. In particular, see Theorem 4.2, which explains the relationship between local and sheaf cohomology.
